# перенос данных между разными сетями

Tags: windows

есть ли какой-нибудь вариант перенести файл с компьютера, который подключен к локальной сети (без интернета), на компьютер, который подключен к сети интернет (без локальной сети), при этом не использовать никаких накопителей (флешки, кабель, диски)?

Answer (score 3):

варианты, конечно, есть:

1. можно запомнить содержимое файла и ввести его на целевом компьютере.
2. можно распечатать содержимое файла и ввести его на целевом компьютере.
3. можно переслать содержимое файла с помощью sms.
4. можно воспользоваться сетью оператора мобильной связи (это ограничение в вопросе не упомянуто).
5. можно скопировать файл на смартфон (это ограничение также не упомянуто в вопросе).
6. можно перенести весь компьютер (это ограничение также не упомянуто в вопросе).

и так далее и тому подобное.